# why the lower right white space is not filled by red

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend, grid

I'm trying to use named lines with grid to do the layout but it doesn't work for me as it should I know where I went wrong because the red section doesn't want to go next to the footer

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [header-start content-start footer-start] 4fr [content-end footer-end section-start] 1fr [header-end section-end];
  grid-template-rows: [header-start] 1fr [hrader-end content-start] 3fr [content-end footer-start] 1fr [footer-end];
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  grid-column: header-start / header-end;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.content {
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
  grid-column: section-start / section-end;
  background-color: coral;
}

footer {
  grid-column: footer-start / footer-end;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}


/*centering*/
.content,
header,
section,
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid2.css">
  <title>grid-line</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      HEADER
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>

    <section class="text">
      TEXT
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `grid-row-end: span 2;` in your **section**

**EDIT:** I missunderstood the question, so I edit the snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [header-start content-start footer-start] 4fr [content-end footer-end section-start] 1fr [header-end section-end];
  grid-template-rows: [header-start] 1fr [hrader-end content-start] 3fr [content-end footer-start] 1fr [footer-end];
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  grid-column: header-start / header-end;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.content {
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
  grid-column: section-start / section-end;
  grid-row-end: span 2;  /* <----  ADD THIS PART */
  background-color: coral;
}

footer {
  grid-column: footer-start / footer-end;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
/*centering*/
.content,
header,
section,
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    HEADER
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>

  <section class="text">
    TEXT
  </section>

  <footer class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid2.css">
  <title>grid-line</title>
  <style>
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(1, 1fr, 150px);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3, 200px, 200px, 200px);
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header header header"
  "content content content section"
  "content content content section"
  "footer footer footer footer";
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  grid-area:header;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.content {
  grid-area:content;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
  grid-area:section;
  background-color: coral;
}

footer {
  grid-area:footer;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}


/*centering*/
.content,
header,
section,
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      HEADER
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>

    <section class="text">
      TEXT
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I thought you were expecting, so just in case, in this one the section spawns next to the content:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid2.css">
  <title>grid-line</title>
  <style>
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(1, 1fr, 150px);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3, 200px, 200px, 200px);
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header header header"
  "content content content section"
  "content content content section"
  "footer footer footer section";
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  grid-area:header;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.content {
  grid-area:content;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
  grid-area:section;
  background-color: coral;
}

footer {
  grid-area:footer;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}


/*centering*/
.content,
header,
section,
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      HEADER
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>

    <section class="text">
      TEXT
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is a simplified way of using the display grid property.